# GCM registration failed

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am working with google push notifications. i am able to retrieve my reg id but its failing to register my mobile in server.Can someone help me where am i going wrong

Main Activity:

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
    // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.

    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    mDisplay.append("Reg id" + regId + " ");
    if (regId.equals("")) {
        // Automatically registers application on startup.
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
        //mDisplay.append("Reg id" + regId + " ");
    } else {
        // Device is already registered on GCM, check server.
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
            // Skips registration.
            //mDisplay.append(getString(R.string.already_registered) + 
           "\n");
           // mDisplay.append("Reg id" + regId + " ");
        } else {
            // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
            // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
            // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
          //  mDisplay.append("Reg id" + regId + " ");
            final Context context = this;
            mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    boolean registered =
                            ServerUtilities.register(context, regId, 
                   userNum);
                    // At this point all attempts to register with the app
                    // server failed, so we need to unregister the device
                    // from GCM - the app will try to register again when
                    // it is restarted. Note that GCM will send an
                    // unregistered callback upon completion, but
                    // GCMIntentService.onUnregistered() will ignore it.
                    if (!registered) {
                        GCMRegistrar.unregister(context);
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    mRegisterTask = null;
                }

            };
            mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
        }
    }
```

Server Utilities:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_ATTEMPTS; i++) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Attempt #" + i + " to register");
        try {
            displayMessage(context, context.getString(
                    R.string.server_registering, i, MAX_ATTEMPTS));
            post(serverUrl, params);
            GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, true);
            String message = context.getString(R.string.server_registered);
            CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Here we are simplifying and retrying on any error; in a real
            // application, it should retry only on unrecoverable errors
            // (like HTTP error code 503).
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to register on attempt " + i, e);
            if (i == MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
                break;
            }
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "Sleeping for " + backoff + " ms before retry");
                Thread.sleep(backoff);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // Activity finished before we complete - exit.
                Log.d(TAG, "Thread interrupted: abort remaining retries!");
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                return false;
            }
            // increase backoff exponentially
            backoff *= 2;
        }
    }
```

server and sender id:

```
 static final String SERVER_URL = "http://http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/Sample";


/**
 * Google API project id registered to use GCM.
 */
static final String SENDER_ID = "921198929963";
```

Error log:

```
01-21 15:32:59.359 19009-19090/? E/GCMRegistrar: internal error: retry  
  receiver class not set yet
01-21 15:32:59.365 19009-19090/? E/Regid:  
APA91bEpJzZoMsj10CzBHXIAxmkyJMyZXTyCUsihO_BhmB-noqc-Llu5uSiaXZBF-
ICCjHtwgNTysoOXyA9715U1kG4L2BV-Zl3vz5DOwk4mTYX9HdF5aBSaOzmLo9zE_ZDz-9ppnThi
01-21 15:32:59.988 19009-19090/? E/SurakshaGCM: Failed to register on 
attempt 1
01-21 15:33:02.215 19009-19090/? E/SurakshaGCM: Failed to register on 
attempt 2
01-21 15:33:06.647 19009-19090/? E/SurakshaGCM: Failed to register on 
attempt 3
01-21 15:33:14.913 19009-19090/? E/SurakshaGCM: Failed to register on 
attempt 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use the latest gcm jar file. If you get the error "internal error: retry receiver class not set yet", then you have an older version of the client gcm.jar. You can download either the source or the updated gcm.jar from the GCM repository.

You may use this tutorial as your guide, the project contains client libraries and samples to explore the GCM APIs: https://github.com/google/gcm